# Get column in where clause subquery part of the results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that uses a sub query in the where clause. I want to get the value in the sub query as part of the results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.col1, b.col2, b.col4
FROM
    tableA a 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT col2, col4 
     FROM tableB
     WHERE (col2) IN ((SELECT c.col2 FROM tableC c 
                       WHERE col3 IN ('', '', '')))) b ON a.col1 = b.col1
```

How can I include c.col3 in the results?

Comment: JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: BTW, most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to get than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: But there is also a column in the tableB which is not available in tableC, if I join the subquery I would not be able to get the column in tableB

Comment: Skip all subqueries, just join all tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `tableC` to provide the values of an `IN` clause then you cannot get those values because they are out-of-scope for the outer query.

Instead, `JOIN` `tableC` to the query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       a.col1,
       b.col2,
       c.col3,
       b.col4
FROM   tableB b
       INNER JOIN tableC c
       ON b.col2 = c.col2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA a 
       ON ON a.col1 = b.col1
WHERE  c.col3 IN (NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

*Note: In Oracle, `''` is identical to `NULL`. You may have redacted some values but what was left is comparing to `NULL` and `x IN (NULL)` is the same as `x = NULL` which is never true so your query would never match any rows. If you really did want to compare to `''` or `NULL` then use `x IS NULL` rather than `=` or `IN`.*